# Delete or change records in ETL 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, row-number

I would like to follow up with a question from my earlier POST: [Delete or change records in ETL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830172/delete-or-change-records-in-etl)

The problem mentioned there was solved with the following:

```
 ; with todelete as (
      select *, 
           count(*) over (partition by label) as cnt, 
           lag(cost) over (partition by label order by time ASC) as lastcost
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by label order by time ASC) as r_number
      from Table1
     )
delete from todelete 
    where cnt > 1 and r_number between 1 and (cnt/2)*2 and  cost=ISNULL(lastcost,cost)
```

, during testing, however, I came across one problem when these movements occur in the table (they cannot be prevented).:

```
label   cost   time
x2       29    14/5/2020 01:00:00
x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
x2       29    15/5/2020 03:12:02
```

That for the same 'Label' I have two identical lines (except timestamp) with the same 'cost'.
And just the above solution will delete these two records. Which I need only the older one to be deleted.

Thx for the advice

UPDATE:

MY goal is.

i have table with records:

```
label   cost   time
x2       29    14/5/2020 01:00:00
x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
x2       30    15/5/2020 03:12:02
```

Now i have delete function:

```
; with todelete as (
          select *, 
               count(*) over (partition by label) as cnt, 
               lag(cost) over (partition by label order by time ASC) as lastcost
               ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by label order by time ASC) as r_number
          from Table1
         )
    delete from todelete 
        where cnt > 1 and r_number between 1 and (cnt/2)*2 and  cost=ISNULL(lastcost,cost)
```

With which I get mine they wanted a table:

```
label   cost   time
x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
x2       30    15/5/2020 03:12:02
```

But the problem occurs when the original table looks like:

```
label   cost   time
x2       29    14/5/2020 01:00:00
x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
x2       29    15/5/2020 03:12:02
```

Now Delete function(mentioned above)

I'll get a table:

```
 label     cost   time
    x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
```

With the above delete function, both records for the label "X2" will be deleted, but I only want to delete the older one.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated my post. I hope it's clearer this way.

Comment: @Casc . . . You still have not described -- *in this question* -- what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Modify my delete function to work as mentioned.

Comment: In your goal table you seem to have updated the cost of the last record from 29 to 30 but in the text you say you want to delete it. Please clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @NickW I just want to have the relevant data in the target table. That's why I'm lubricating. Moves come to the table and it can happen that for the same value in the column "label" for example "x2" another row comes with the value "x2" but a different cost. Therefore, it has a delete function that works in this case. But it doesn't work when we have the value "x2" with the cost"29" in the "label" column. When the next line "x2" comes in and the price is "29", my delete function deletes both records. And I just don't want that. I want to keep the newer line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody anything?

I try this:
I couldn't solve it.
Here in this you see that it will delete both records for me (I just want the older one):
https://rextester.com/TLLQ93275

In this case, it works correctly, but if "x2" has the same price (for example, 29), it will also delete both entries.
https://rextester.com/RHB70490

UPDATE:

I finally managed to solve the problem. I added another ranking function and conditioned it appropriately.

```
; with todelete as (
      select *, 
           count(*) over (partition by label) as cnt, 
     lag(cost) over (partition by label order by time ASC) as lastcost
     ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by label order by time ASC) as r_number
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by label order by time DESC) as r_number2
    ,RANK() over (partition by cost order by time asc) as TEST
    ,Row_NUMBER() over (partition by label order by TIME DESC) as TEST2
       from Table1
     )
DELETE from todelete 
    where (cnt > 1 and r_number between 1 and (cnt/2)*2 and cost=ISNULL(lastcost,cost) AND TEST2 !=1)  OR (cnt>1 AND TEST2<>1 AND r_number2 != 1)
```

For illustration, here: https://rextester.com/DONME54328